# Xamarin and Navigation

Tags: xamarin, sdk

I am looking for an SDK that is compatible with Xamarin and includes Navigation, turn-by turn directions.  I am looking for a data set or real time API calls that I can incorporate with my Xamarin platform usage.

Comment: requests for third party tools and libraries are explicitly off topic

Comment: ok, didn't know